# Фотография с камеры из android.app.Service

Tags: java, android, камера

Я создаю приложение, которое из `Service` делает фотографию с задней камеры телефона. Но во время выполнения у меня вылетает исключение:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

Вот исходный код моего `Service`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class I2 extends Service {

    byte[] i1;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent i1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent i1, int i2) {
        new Thread(new i1()).start();
        return;
    }

    private class i1 implements Runnable {

        private byte[] i1 = null;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Camera i1 = Camera.open();
                    i1.setPreviewDisplay(new SurfaceView(I2.this).getHolder());
                    i1.startPreview();
                    i1.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] i1, Camera i2) {
                            I2.this.i1 = i1; //получаю byte картинки
                            i2.stopPreview();
                            i2.release();
                        }

                    });
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    Log.v("", "lnp_ " + e1.toString());
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

В файле `AndroidManifest.xml` разрешение на камеру добавил:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

В интернете нашёл примеры проектов работы с камерой и нашёл следующее: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/hardware/camera-hardware/android-camera-example/ но всё-равно та же самая ошибка! Подскажите, как её исправить?

Comment: Я начал использовать в своей системе видео наблюдения дешёвые Android телефоны вместо дорогих видеокамер, стоимость которых достигает 20 тысяч рублей. Так что никаких уязвимостей и хитростей я делать не собираюсь.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121660/how-to-record-video-from-background-of-application-android попробуйте, может поможет.

Comment: К сожалению, та же ошибка. Исключение вылетает в следующей строке: `Camera i1 = Camera.open();`. Я пробовал добавить аргументы `0`, `1`, `2`... в метод `open`.

Comment: Разрешения на пользование камерой запрашивали https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html? Что возвращает `Camera.getNumberOfCameras();`?

Comment: @YuraIvanov, а Вы знаете, у меня получилось. Действительно, после этой команды заработало на виртуальном телефоне. Сейчас попробую на обычном протестировать.

Comment: Не работает, @Yuralvanov. Эта функция возвращает 2. А что дальше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед тем, как получать доступ камере, и уж тем более фотографировать, необходимо вот эту строчку вписать:

```
Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
```

Спасибо пользователю @Yura Ivanov.

---

Если программируете на эмуляторе Android версии 5.0 и выше, то, надо зайти в Настройки -> Приложения -> "Имя Вашего приложения" -> Разрешения -> Camera поставить галочку